# AS3: How to intersect vectors at runtime?

Tags: actionscript-3, vector-graphics

Let's say I use the Graphics class at runtime to draw some vector shapes dynamically. For example a square and a circle.

Is there a way to create a new shape at runtime where those 2 vectors shapes overlap?

Those kind of operations are very common in all vector design programs such as Illustrator, Corel, etc... but I haven't found anything in Adobe's documentation, nor anywhere else, to do it by code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although drawing operations on the Graphics class are described in terms of lines, points etc this is - as far as you're concerned - just telling it what to draw onto a bitmap. There's no way to remove a shape once drawn, short of clear(), which just wipes the whole thing clean.

I don't fully understand why, as the vector data must be retained - there's no loss of quality on scaling after drawing, for example.

If you don't want to get into some hardcore maths (for anything beyond straight lines, you'll need to) there's an answer here which might help if you've ever used PixelBender:

[How to calculate intersection between shapes in flash / action script ? (access to shape's segments and nodes?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527032/how-to-calculate-intersection-between-shapes-in-flash-action-script-access)

Failing that, if it's just cosmetic you could play around with masking shapes (will probably end up quite hacky though) - however, if you actually want to use the intersection to draw or describe a shape you will need to dig out your maths book or look for a good graphics library.

Hope this helps

Comment: My first approach was masking, but then the measures of the Sprite are not correct as they include the hidden parts as well. As for using Pixel Bender, it could work... but it's not what I'm looking for. I have upvoted your answer, but will wait before marking it as accepted. Thanks for the input.

Comment: So are you actually looking for a mathematical description of the intersected space, in the sense of a vector shape that can be redrawn, or are you just after the graphic? If you want the shape masking will not work, you will need to calculate it. I think you might want to look into Quad trees to optimise the process of checking, but I've not had to do it before so I'm not 100%